# How to fix jsonlite lexical errors

Tags: r, json

I am trying to get data from  an API using httr and jsonlite  in R and this is the error  message I am getting,

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <!DOCTYPE html>  <!-- paulirish
                     (right here) ------^
```

can anyone help me out, I am new in R

I used httr and jsonlite

Comment: Welcome to SO! The string you are passing to `jsonlite` (`<!DOCTYPE html>  <!-- paulirish ...`) does not look like a JSON response, there's likely something wrong with your request or perhaps even API service itself is having issues, that received HTML response probably includes more hints about what went wrong. Please try to add more details to your question (what API, how did you make the request, how did you verify that the request itself was OK), I'm afraid there's not mutch we can help you with based on the current info alone.

Comment: library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

res2<-httr::GET("https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/docs/api#resources-ontologies-links")
str(res2)


str(res2$content)
response<-httr::content(res2,as="text")
str(response)

responseJSON<- jsonlite::fromJSON(response) # thank you, this is the script I used,  am trying to get information from Ontology lookup Services.

Comment: Please include additional information in the question -- you can still edit it. That's a link for API documentation, for actual API requests check `Example request` in each section for an curl example. i.e. to retrieve efo ontology,  `$ curl -L 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/api/ontologies/efo' -i -H 'Accept: application/json' `  example in documentation  translates to `httr::content(httr::GET('http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/api/ontologies/efo'))` (returnes parsed JSON)

Comment: Hi thank for the information, i want to be able to get the ontology information in a table form so that i can annotate my data with ontologies to build a database I guess I could use R to make the annotation easier.